# Undefined Reference SDL2 C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been trying to compile a SDL2 code in C++, a console application. I use Code::Blocks with GNU GCC Complier.  This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialise! SDL Error: " << SDL_GetError( )<< std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It gives me these errors:

```
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

I have "-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2" **in the other linker options**, and and in **Search directories** I put:

- ......\SDL2-devel-2.0.5-mingw\SDL2-2.0.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include in **Compiler**
- ......\SDL2-devel-2.0.5-mingw\SDL2-2.0.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib in
  **Linker**

I moved all include, lib and bin files to the MinGW's folders.

Any idea of what's what I'm doing badly?

Thank you!

Comment: How exactly does your linker command line look like? Remember: Order of librbaries and objects matters when linking.

Comment: Try writing `#undef main` on the line before `int main(...)`

Comment: Any reason not to use cmake?

Comment: @ErikW Why, what might have already defined it? It certainly should not be.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Which command line? This? E:\Desktop\Ander-Laquin\Dev\Programming\C-C++\SDL2-devel-2.0.5-mingw\SDL2-2.0.5\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib

Comment: @LaquinLaquih That is a path, not a command line.

Comment: @underscore_d I think SDL2 redefines main in windows, if my memory serves me right. I know that I had some problems without undefining main

Comment: Have you tried compiling it from the shell? Like `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe -lSDL2`

Comment: @Erik W I've tried with #undef main and it fixed WinMain@16 error, but the others are still there.

Comment: Undefining main is a bad idea unless you absolutely know what you're doing (and in that case you wouldn't be asking questions), and is addressed by SDL FAQ. What is a full compile command (I suppose your IDE should show it during the build) and what is its full output? It is quite likely that you're using 32bit compiler but trying to link 64bit libraries, which just fails to find symbols on windows (instead of reporting wrong library architecture, like on other systems).

Comment: Can we see the command to compile it?

Answer (score -4):

For [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), the [sdl](/questions/tagged/sdl) header file in the include directive must be:

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

`<SDL2/SDL.h>` is used for [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) systems.

Comment: It all depends on how you configure your build system, no? In any case, it couldn't cause undefined reference error.